# Editing database while connected to vb.net

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, datasource, oledb

is it okay to edit database (MS Access) while it is connected to vb? I'm using `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\employeedb.mdb;` I'll just add a few rows as my HR provided me. Thanks :)

Comment: A little research here (via searches) would not only have told you that this is possible, but would have found you code samples for doing so. Please put some effort into research first before posting a new question here; chances are quite good that the question has been asked (and answered) here before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new to programming as a whole and correct me or anyone can if i'm wrong.

Yes you can add a row or two. I once used access and added a few rows without encountering any problems.